# 'Statement Expected' Syntax Error Highlighting on First Line of JS File in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have a JS file where no matter what is put on the first line (comment or code), PHPStorm lists a syntax error.  When I hover over the error, the description says "Statement Expected".  What it looks like:

[image]

Is this a bug with the IDE or something that can be disabled?

**EDIT**

Sample file [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52967366576547921699)

Comment: Please upload that file somewhere (yes, actual file, not just contents on its own) and share the link. But before that: 1) create another file anywhere in your project and copy-paste from this one -- see if error will remain there as well. if not -- compare file lengths. 2) Try "File | Invalidate Caches.." -- maybe some internal index corruption (sometimes happens for PHP files)

Comment: @LazyOne I created another file and the same error highlight appears.  Tried the 'File' -> 'Invalidate Caches' route and still the same problem.  I added a link to the sample file in the question

Comment: Seeing the same error on phpstorm 7.1.3. But the error goes away if you remove the leading space in front of `var myApp`. At second glance.. I don't think that's a space.. some other leading white-space character causing issues.

Comment: I think that character is ascii 239, not a space.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have **UTF-8 BOM signature** (`EF BB BF`) just before `var myApp=` line (first code line in that file)

[image]

If you remove it IDE will stop complaining.

**P.S.**
Yes -- IDE should be smarter in such case and should provide better error message and error location. Feel free to submit new ticket to the Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: This was good. I simply re-typed my function declaration, pasted the guts, and the issue went away. I agree JetBrains should be better at catching this one. I'll cross-post it over to their tracker.

Comment: @Imperative Please try **"Zero Width Characters locator" plugin** -- it has separate inspection and can detect such case (work OK with a file from your example).

Comment: Good to know. I linked this out of the issue but I'll mention this to them anyway. That makes it even easier to implement a fix.

Answer (score 4):

In most of the cases this issue occurs due to copy paste.
There may be some characters/line feed which may need to rewrite in your IDE.

In such cases simply copy your code to notepad and again copy it back to your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off "Properties > Languages & Frameworks > Template Data Languages" and error "statement expected" will go out.
[image]

Comment: Because this syntax is not correct for setted template. In my example, in the project i use php and angularjs, but phpstorm does not make defferences between them.